# Creating resources in a maven/java project

Tags: java, maven

How do I create a resource so that it is located in the resource folder of my project?
In the following, "test.txt" is a file I want to create, but the variable:url is null, so I can't get a path to the file I want to create.

```
    URL url= HashArray.class.getResource("test.txt");
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

The resource probably needs to be located in the resources folder because I need to bundle it with the code in the packaging phase.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you want to do this? Is this a maven plugin by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work, as resources is not a runtime location. It's a source location. If you try to put a file, and run your program the url wouldn't be null anymore. But it would point to your target/classes folder (ok there are quite a number of possiblities, depending how exactly you start it) However, in most cases it wouldn't be resources anymore...

Comment: If you write to resources you can't read it while runtime using the resource loading mechanism. If you want to write to classpath you need a clear definition where you want to write to. As the classpath consists mainly of a number of jars thats a problem. Maybe you just rethink the situation and figure out something completely different.

Comment: I guess the resources mechanism isn't really meant to be written into by the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is not relation between the resource folder in maven and a resource in Java.

`class.getResource` finds a resource in the classpath, you are fine putting your *txt* file in the *resources folder* but in order to make it accessible at runtime you have to package it.

[How to package resources](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fakegame/index.php?title=How_to_handle_resources_with_maven)